# $N = N_0 + N_1 + N_2 + N_3$ What is the derivative of each term wrt. $N_1$?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm not even sure if this is possible to solve. All I know for sure is the following:

$$ \frac{dN_1}{dN_1} = 1 \text{ and }  \begin{cases}
    N = N_0 + N_1 + N_2 + N_3\\
    N_0 = N - N_1 - N_2 - N_3\\
    N_1 = N - N_0 - N_2 - N_3\\
    N_2 = N - N_0 - N_1 - N_3\\
    N_3 = N - N_0 - N_1 - N_2\\
\end{cases} $$
$$
\text{Thus }\frac{d}{dN_1} (N - N_0 - N_2 - N_3)= 1
$$
$$
\text{and therefore }\frac{dN}{dN_1} - \frac{dN_0}{dN_1} - \frac{dN_2}{dN_1} -  \frac{dN_3}{dN_1}= 1
$$
This seems totally circular, so I'm not even sure if it's possible to solve the derivatives of these terms wrt. $N_1$.

What if instead of a full derivative, I only want a partial?
My intuition tells me
$\frac{\partial N}{\partial N_1} = 1$ and $\frac{\partial N_{i\neq 1}}{\partial N_1} = -1$, but I'm really not sure how to justify this.

$\textbf{N is a constant}$ so $\frac{\partial N}{\partial N_1} \neq 1$.
$$N = \sum_{i=0}^3 N_i$$

Comment: If $N$ is a constant then $\frac{\partial N}{\partial N_1} =0\ne 1.$

Comment: garbage it/garbage out.  What *are* then $N_1$?  Constants? Variables? Variables in terms of what?  Functions? Variables mutually dependent on other terms.  I don't think the question even makes sense unless we clear that up.

Comment: but for variables if $u = w+x + y + z$ and then $\frac {dx}{dx} = 1$ and $\frac {du}{dx} = \frac {d(w+x+y+z)}{dx} = \frac {dw}{dx} + \frac {dx}{dx}+\frac {dy}{dx}+ \frac {dz}{dz} = \frac{dw}{dx} + 1 + \frac {dy}{dx} +\frac {dz}{dx}$ and so $\frac {du}{dx}-\frac {dw}{dx} -\frac{dy}{dx} -\frac {dz}{dx} = 1$.  There's nothing circular about that and, no, you *don't* know anything about what $\frac {dw}{dx}$ or any of the others are.

Comment: I cleared that up best I can. All I know is that N is a constant equal to the sum of the N_i terms. The terms individually can change as long as the sum remains constant. Hope that helps.

Comment: If $N_1$ is a constant then $\frac {d(N_1)}{dN_1}$ or $\frac {d\ anything}{dN_1}$ does not mean anything at all.

Comment: Note even $\frac {dN_1}{dN_1} = 0$ if 1) $N_1$ is  a constant and ii) if $\frac {d\ anything}{d\ constant}$ is considered to be meaningful.  If $\frac {dN_1}{dN_1}$ means anything, it means $\lim \frac{{N_1}_{N_1 + h} +{N_1}_{N_1}}{h} = \lim \frac {N_1 - N_1}h=\lim \frac {0}h = 0$.  (${N_1}_K$ means $N_1$ evaluated with input of $K$.  But as $N_1$ is constant it will always be evaluated at $N_1$ no matter what the "input")

Comment: @fleablood That does not mean $N_1$ is a constant. Ex: $1+5+6+2 = 14 = 7 + 7 +0 + 0$.   They can change together as long as the sum remains constant. $dx/dx \neq 0$

Comment: Then what the mother loving blue-eyed heck *ARE* these little squirming abominations you call $N_i$?  This question can't have an answer if it doesn't make *any* sense and right now the question is spewing meaningless gobbledeegook.  Equations on invariable (whether the value is determined or not) values can't have derivatives and you a derivative in term of an invariable is meaningless.  This question is literally without meaning or sense.  It is meaningless non-sense.

Comment: Okay.... $N$ is a constant.  $N_i$ are variables.  Yes, you are correct. But as $\frac {dN}{dN_1} = 0$ we have $\frac {dN_0}{dN_1} + \frac {dN_2}{dN_1} + \frac {dN_3}{dN_1}=-1$.  But you have no idea nor any way of solving any of the $\frac {dN_k}{dN_1}$. You only know what the sum of the three are.

Comment: You know that for any $i= 0,1,2,3$ that $\sum_{k\ne i} \frac {dN_k}{dN_i} = -1$.  Nothing circular about that.  And that's all you know (other than the obvious $\frac {dN_k}{dN_k} = 1$ and $\frac {dN}{dN_k} = 0$.)

Comment: @fleablood Thank you. I did say in the question I wasn't sure if it was solvable.